# Converting Formula field to a currency field

Tags: formula-field, currency

Can we change a Formula field into Currency field . I need to change a formula field into Currency field . As per salesforce standard feature we are not able to change a formula data type into any other data type . Please let em know is there any option to do so.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cant. But what you can do is to create a currency field and repopulate the values from the formula field using data loader and then just get rid of the old formula field.
Hope that helps

Comment: How to give 'accepted'?